# Unable to insert date to table

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to insert a date into oracle table using below

```
SQL> insert into temp (tst,thistime) values ('test3',TO_DATE('MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI
:SS','01/01/2014 16:45:45') );
```

but its giving below error

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01821: date format not recognized
```

Below is the description of table

```
SQL> describe temp;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ---------------------------

 TST                                                VARCHAR2(10)
 THISTIME                                           DATE
```

Comment: You've got the arguments to do_date reversed. Please check the docs.

Comment: Yes.Its mistake..now i got it..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `insert . . . select` form of `insert`:

```
insert into temp (tst, thistime)
    select 'test3', TO_DATE('01/01/2014 16:45:45', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    from dual;
```

In addition to having the arguments backwards for `to_date()`, `values` doesn't evaluate expressions that belong in a `select` statement.